# Using an object as filepath for extracting multiple icons from exe files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pywin32

I'm trying to extract icons from a number of programs of which I have the filepath. I've managed to extract a single icon from a hard-coded filepath, though, with the same syntax i.e. "C:....\filename.exe" but stored in an object, win32gui.ExtractIconEx tells me it can't find the filepath specified.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.font as font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

root = Tk()
window = Canvas(root, bg='#2e2e2e',highlightthickness=0)

Density = 9

size = int(1024 / Density)

hor=int(Density)
ver=int(hor / 2.1)

AddIMG = Image.open(r'Assets\AddImage.png')
AddIMG = AddIMG.resize((size,size), Image.NEAREST)
Addphoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(AddIMG)

Grid.rowconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)

for x in range(hor):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
    for y in range(ver):
        Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
        add_button = Button(frame, image=Addphoto, fg='white', bg='#2e2e2e', relief='flat', borderwidth=1)
        add_button.grid(row=y, column=x, sticky=NSEW)
        add_button.config(command=lambda column=x, row=y: toplevel(column, row))

def open_app(path):
    root.destroy()
    exit(os.system(path))

for N in range(hor * ver):
    all_lines = open('Filepath.txt', 'r')
    all_lines_variable = all_lines.readlines()
    if all_lines_variable[N].startswith('C:/'):
        path = all_lines_variable[N]
        path = path.rstrip('\n')
        path = str('"' + path + '"')
        print(path)
        R = int(N / Density)
        C = int(N % Density)

        name = str('icon ' + str(R) + ' ' + str(C) + '.png')
        print(name)
        ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
        ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

        large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(path, 0)
        win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

        hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
        hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_x)
        hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

        hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
        hdc.DrawIcon((0, 0), large[0])
        hbmp.SaveBitmapFile(hdc, name)

        AppIMG = Image.open(name)
        AppIMG = AppIMG.resize((size, size), Image.NEAREST)
        AppPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(AppIMG)

        App_path = all_lines_variable[N]
        App_button = Button(frame, image=AppPhoto, fg='white', bg='#2e2e2e', relief='flat', borderwidth=1)
        App_button.grid(row=R, column=C, sticky=NSEW)
        App_button.config(command=lambda path=path: open_app(path))
root.mainloop()
```

This code snippet may be long, but it should be runnable.
The part regarding my question is after the function "open_app"
hope anyone can help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python projects\Hotkey software\Hotkey.pyw", line 146, in <module>
    large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx("path", 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'ExtractIconEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for reminding me, it has been updated

Comment: The error shows you using a hardcoded pathname of `"path"`. Do you expect it to literally find a file with the four-character name "path"? Also, that error message doesn't seem to match the code you posted.

Comment: Why are you doing this `str('"' + path + '"')`?

Comment: @8349697 I have the filepath to the file I need the icon of in an object called path, I'm currently only using rpath but the path = str(' " ' + path + ' " ') was still left over from an earlier attempt. I've also been trying to import rpath into the function as r'%s' but even that didn't work

Comment: When you read a line from a file, your path is already a string. You don't need to add `"` to the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Plus, you open the same file over and over in a loop. Is that how it should be?

Comment: I created a text file with a path and ran the piece of code related to extracting the icon. `ExtractIconEx` function works with `path = path.rstrip('\n')`. The icon is saved in a PNG image.